# How to make \PassOptionsToPackage add the option as the last option?

Tags: babel, warnings, abnt

I am having the warning:

```
Package babel Warning: Last declared language option is `english',(babel) but the last processed one was `brazil'.
```

Because the class I use is badly and has hard coded the babel option:

```
\RequirePackage[brazil]{babel}
```

But I need to use `english` on the document. Doing:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{english}{babel}
\documentclass[brazil,english]{abntex2}
```

Seems to be passing the option to babel as:

```
\RequirePackage[english,brazil]{babel}
```

Instead of:

```
\RequirePackage[brazil,english]{babel}
```

---

## Update

Adding MWE:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{english}{babel}

\documentclass[
    10pt,
    openright,
    twoside,
    a5paper,
    brazil,
    english
    ]{abntex2}

\begin{document}

Hello World!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)!(as always)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{main=english}{babel}
```

if you want English as the main language of your document or

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{english,main=brazil}{babel}
```

if you want Brazil to be the main language of your document and English an additional language:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{main=english}{babel}

\documentclass[
    10pt,
    openright,
    twoside,
    a5paper,
    ]{abntex2}

\begin{document}

Current language is \languagename.

\end{document}
```

results in

[image: Current language is english.]

and

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{english,main=brazil}{babel}

\documentclass[
    10pt,
    openright,
    twoside,
    a5paper,
    ]{abntex2}

\begin{document}

Current language is \languagename.

\end{document}
```

results in

[image: Current language is brazil.]

Both results without warning.

Comment: Your first two lines use brackets instead of (curly) braces. Is there a reason for that.

Comment: @TeXnician Only my personal inadequacy. Fixed. Thanks you.